# Pass directory to C++ application from compiler

Tags: c++, directory, autotools

Some applications contain scripts that are run by the main application that reside in /usr/libexec. However, the autoconf scripts are able to change that directory by passing `--libexecdir` to the configure script.

For example, when running `./configure` in the `git` source code, I can set `--libexecdir` to any directory I want, and the program will still work.

What do I need to add to a C++ to make this functionality work? In other words, how can I have a directory name set by a configure script compiled into the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the value of the `@libexecdir@` substitution variable (as used in e.g. `Makefile.in`) to be exposed to your C++ code.  The simplest and most reliable way to do that is with a `-D` switch on the compiler command line for the object file that needs to know:

```
foo.o: CPPFLAGS += -DLIBEXECDIR='"$(libexecdir)"'
```

In `foo.cc`, `LIBEXECDIR` will then be a preprocessor macro expanding to a string constant that has the path you need.  Two caveats, though: The above Makefile snippet uses a GNU make feature, [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).  It will not work in other Make implementations.  Also, I didn't bother quoting any characters in the expansion of `$(libexecdir)`.  Fully defensive quoting would look something like this:

```
foo.o: CPPFLAGS += \
  -DLIBEXECDIR='"$(subst ",\",$(subst ','\'',$(subst \,\\,$(libexecdir))))"'
```

You will definitely need at least the innermost `$(subst ...)` construct if you want to be able to use Windows pathnames, with the slashes going the wrong way.  People don't usually put <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd> in pathnames, so I probably wouldn't bother with the outer two until someone complained.

The same technique will work for any `@whatever@` substitution variable that isn't also an `AC_DEFINE`.

---

You might think you could use `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` somehow to get the value of `$(libexecdir)` into `config.h` and so avoid all this mucking around with the command line.  Unfortunately, Autoconf doesn't fully compute the value of its `@*dir@` substitutions at configure time:

```
# near the top of the generated 'configure':
exec_prefix=NONE
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'

# much, much later -- as part of AC_OUTPUT:
test "x$exec_prefix" = xNONE && exec_prefix='${prefix}'
```

Therefore, if you do the obvious thing with `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED`, you will get something like

```
#define LIBEXECDIR "${exec_prefix}/libexec"
```

in your config.h.  So that's not going to work, and I don't see a good way to make it work.